# Sequelize use included model in where-object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using **[Sequelize.js](http://sequelizejs.com/)** with **nodejs** on a server

It is possible to eager load associated models like this:

```
User.findAll({ include: [ Task ] })
```

Given this example, is there a way to **access the Tasks properties directly** in a where-object like so?

```
User.findAll({where:{Task.getId() = 1}},{ include: [ Task ] })
```

Or can this only be achieved by a seperate functioncall?

Comment: I am surprised by how little upvotes this question has, it's a very common problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the include to an object with model and where properties

```
User.findAll({
  include: [ { 
    model: Task 
    where: { id: 1 }
  }] 
})
```